# warning: RLMNotificationToken released without unregistering

Tags: ios, realm

I'm using RLM Notifications in a context of a UITableView that is a subview of a UIViewController with a UIPageViewDelegate. The ViewControllers are kind of created on the fly and are destroyed after swiping to the next ViewController. But it's always possible to swipe back one page. For this reason I can't destroy the notification token.
But then I get the warning:

```
RLMNotificationToken released without unregistering a notification. You must hold on to the RLMNotificationToken returned from addNotificationBlock and call removeNotification: when you no longer wish to recieve RLMRealm notifications.
```

How can I surpress this warning since it's pointless?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is logged when the notification token is deallocated is to prevent users from accidentally forgetting to hold a strong reference to it for the duration that they wish to receive notifications.

I encourage you to call [`-[RLMNotificationToken stop]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMNotificationToken.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMNotificationToken(im)stop) when you no longer want to receive change notifications.

To suppress this warning, you should call `removeNotification` when you no longer care to receive them (e.g. when your ViewController's are dismissed).

Even though deallocating the notification token has the same effect, calling `-stop` will better communicate the intention there.

Comment: Is this right? According to the docs: notifications are automatically unregistered when the notification token is deallocated. I have confirmed my VCs deinit is being called. Assuming Realm only has a weak reference, the token should be released, and so it should not be causing a memory leak. If Realm has a strong reference, it wouldn't be aware the VC has gone, so it wouldn't be able to spit out the message. I think the message exists for people who forget to keep a reference to the token.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment, you're right. I've rewritten my answer to better reflect what's happening. Let me know if you have more questions.